# Listening for data, is while(true) the correct solution? Java

Tags: java, while-loop

I have faced a problem i hope someone here can help me with. Right now, I have used way too many while(true) loops in my program, so it runs a little slow.

I'm not sure if i am doing something wrong with my code, or if this is the only solution.

Have a class which receive data (doubles) from another class. Want to start a while loop which only should run when the data is not 0. Some code i have here:

```
while (true) {
        while (kWh != 0) {
            try {
                queue.put(kWh);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {                  
                System.out.println("Could not put data into queue");
            }
            kWh = 0;
        }   
    }





@Override
public void SendPower(double power_data) throws RemoteException {
    ReceivePowerData.kWh = power_data;              
}
```

As you can see, when the SendPower method runs, the kWh variable gets updated. When this variable is not 0, i want the while loop to run and insert the value to the queue. My problem is that i am using while(true) so it keeps running that loop, even when no data are received, and that is a waste.

What can i else do? any idea?

**Update**

I have tried to use the wait(); method, and that seem to work, it waits.. but i don't know how i should implement the notify(); method which should start it again.

code:

```
synchronized (this) {
        System.out.println("Wait for response from sensor");
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Continue");

        while (kWh != 0) {
            try {
                queue.put(kWh);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {                  
                System.out.println("Could not put data into queue");
            }
            kWh = 0;
        }   

    }
```

Then i tried to code it in the method, but i really think this is wrong..

```
@Override
public void SendPower(double power_data) throws RemoteException {
    ReceivePowerData.kWh = power_data;  

    synchronized (this) {
        notify();   
    }

}
```

So when the SendPower method are called from another program, it should run, and then it should start, but this does not work.. am i close?

Comment: Do a search on "notifying an object's monitor": should set you on your way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. give a hint? what should i google for :=?

Comment: Exactly the sentence I give you. Some useful articles come up in the top 10. There's quite a lot of terminology for you to get to grips with; my sentence will eventually mean a lot to you.

Comment: Take a look at `SynchronousQueue` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html

Comment: Inner while loop will not goes for loop but while(true) will always running. You should break or use some boolean variable ;)

Comment: Bathsheba, could you take a look at the update section.. have tried to use wait and notify, but when the notify runs, it do not start the while loop

Answer (score 5):

You can use the observer pattern. Java has standard interfaces to implement it.

There are loads of tutorials on this pattern in Java

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm

This is a very simplistic example.

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.Random;

public class ObserverPattern {
    private static class PowerObserverable extends Observable implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                double kwh = random.nextDouble() * 4;
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(kwh);
            }
        }
    }

    // Make sure this class is thread safe
    private static class PowerObserver implements Observer {
        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object kwh) {
            System.out.println(kwh);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PowerObserverable observerable = new PowerObserverable();
        observerable.addObserver(new PowerObserver());

        new Thread(observerable).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the standard interfaces? The second link only uses POJOs.

Comment: java.util.Observer and java.util.Observable

Comment: This could be a great answer if there was an actual example for his code.

Comment: The Java example on wikipedia is very concise, either way I'll add a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a interrupted sleep like what is described here [Interrupt a sleeping thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144817/interrupt-a-sleeping-thread) or

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/thread_interruption.shtml
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/Threadsleepandinterrupt.htm

As you can see an active pooling loop is always the worst solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use of [Guarded Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

Note that the queue is only accessed in `synchronized` methods, so doesn't need to be a synchronized queue.

```
private final Queue<Integer> queue = ArrayDeque<Integer>();

public synchronized void addKWh(int kwh){
   queue.put(kWh);
   notifyAll(); //tell other thread queue has something
}

//running on other thread
public synchronized void efficientQueueProcessor() { 
    while (true) { //really should have an exit condition
        Integer kwh = null;
        synchronized { //mainly because wait() must be in sync, but also for queue
            Integer kwh = queue.poll();
            if (kwh == null) {
              //queue is empty
              wait(); //thread will wait here efficiently until something is added
              continue; //so null is not processed
            }
        }
        processFigure(kwh); // out of sync block
    }
}

public void processFigure(int kwh){
    // do work with kwh
}
```

Invoke a method to add, it is bad form to set public fields:

```
@Override
public void SendPower(double power_data) throws RemoteException {
    ReceivePowerData.addKWh(power_data);
}
```